# Server-side routing with react-router v4

Tags: express, react-router

As you may know, react-router updated to v4 and changed a lot of thinkgs and syntaxes. Whenever I try to acces a route manually it gives me the error `Cannot Get/`, but works when I add `#`. I'm looking to be able to go to the route with express js whether I insert the rout manually in the broswer input or not. Thank you!

Here's a piece of code

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <nav>
            <div className="nav-wrapper">
              <a href="#" className="brand-logo">Logo</a>
              <ul id="nav-mobile" className="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/login">Login</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/register">Register</Link></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
          <Match exactly pattern="/" component={Home} />
          <Match pattern="/login" component={Login} />
          <Match pattern="/register" component={Register} />

          <Miss component={NoMatch}/>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you handle your routes on the server?For react and react-router to work as expected you have to ensure at least two things(and in a specific order!) on the express-side:

1. Your static file-serving middleware is configured correctly and mounted to your express app.
2. You have a catch-all route handler that always serves your initial application bundle(usually your index.html and the application scripts).
   For example:

   `//app is the express application instance
   //setup static file handling with express.static middleware
   app.use('/', express.static('path_to_your_static_files'));
   //
   //this will match all routes
   app.get('/*', (req,res) => {
       //serve your app here....
   });`

Every request that isn't handled by your static middleware will eventually make it to this handler, just make sure you mount in the correct order.With the above example, everything you "manually" enter will result in a response from the server so be sure to handle 404 and other special cases from your client router